# Change title in App Bar when user navigates to a different component in React

Tags: reactjs, material-design

I have a React app with a bunch of components and have it structured in the following way

```
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <ResponsiveDrawer>
          <div className="App">
              <div>
                <Route exact path="/" component={Administrator} />
                <Route path="/admin" component={Administrator} />
                <Route exact path="/jobs" component={Jobs} />
                <Route path="/jobs/:id" render={({match}) => <ViewJob id={match.params.id} />} />
                <Route path="/entries/:jobId/:entryId" render={({match}) => <Entry jobId={match.params.jobId} entryId={match.params.entryId} />} />
                <Route exact path="/reports" component={Reports} />
                <Route path="/reports/:jobId" render={({match}) => <JobReport id={match.params.jobId} />} />
                <Route path="/reports/activity" component={ActivityReport} />
              </div>
          </div>
         </ResponsiveDrawer>
     </Router>

    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Part of the ResponsiveDrawer contains a title that I want to change based on which component the user is currently in. Is there any way that I can pass props up to a parent like that?

Answer (score 0):

if you're not using redux, you can add a switch-case statement in the componentDidMount of the ResponsiveDrawer component based on location.pathname.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following method.

1. Read the URL of the current page using window.location.href.Since on each page, `ResponsiveDrawer` is present.So from the current URL you can map title of a page in `ResponsiveDrawer` component.
2. If you are using `redux` then from each component you can update a global title variable in store.And then connect `ResponsiveDrawer` to store and show title.

Comment: Thanks! How would this work if I want the title to be different than the URL. For instance some of my urls are products/editproduct/:id and I don't want to expose this to the user

Comment: You can map url to title in your ResponsiveDrawer component.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try something like this using `this.context.router`.

```
class App extends Component {
  findComponent = () => {
    switch (this.context.router.history.location.pathname.split('/')[0]) {
      case 'admin':
        return 'Administrator';
      // ...
      default:
        return 'Administrator';
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
     <Router>
       <ResponsiveDrawer component={this.findComponent()}>
         {/* Your routes */}
       </ResponsiveDrawer>
     </Router>
    );
  }
}

App.contextTypes = {
  router: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};
```

Comment: Thanks for that idea. I get the error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'pathname' of undefined